# Why is my text messed up in Firefox 3.5 in Windows 7? (see pic) How can I fix this?

Tags: windows-7, firefox3.5

It only happens on some web pages, and only for some text items.  On splurb.com, it is happening all over:

http://scottelkin.com/images/splurb.jpg

Comment: it looks like the website is using a different character encoding than your browser is.

Comment: Can you include source code or a scrape of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Going to splurb.com it looks like the font used is in the family of Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif(lifted from the css).  Those fonts should be included into windows.  Perhaps they have been removed.  Make sure those fonts are installed.

Comment: actually, i am having a problem with helvetica.  how do i reinstall it?